# How to apply a style to a substring of text in Indesign?

Tags: vb.net, scripting, adobe-indesign

How can I select a substring of text from my Cell, so that I can apply a character style?

This works fine when I'm only selecting a single character:

```
If IsNumeric(para.Contents.ToString.Substring(0, 1)) 
    doc.Selection = para.Characters.ItemByRange(1, 1)
    doc.Selection.Item(1).appliedCharacterStyle = mycharstyle
End If
```

but it fails if I try to select a range of characters

```
doc.Selection = myCell.Characters.ItemByRange(72, 76)
```

The error is

> Invalid valid for set property 'Selection. Expected Array of Objects, Object or idNothingEnum enumerator, but received (Character, Character, Character, Character, Character)

I think there must be some entirely different technique to apply my CharacterStyle to a substring of text in my Cell, but after searching high-and-low I've yet to discover it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with GREP instead.

```
        app.FindGrepPreferences = idNothingEnum.idNothing
        app.ChangeGrepPreferences = idNothingEnum.idNothing
        app.FindChangeGrepOptions.IncludeFootnotes = False
        app.FindChangeGrepOptions.IncludeHiddenLayers = False
        app.FindChangeGrepOptions.IncludeLockedLayersForFind = False
        app.FindChangeGrepOptions.IncludeLockedStoriesForFind = False
        app.FindChangeGrepOptions.IncludeMasterPages = False
        mycharstyle = doc.CharacterStyles("SK-number1")
        app.ChangeGrepPreferences.AppliedCharacterStyle = mycharstyle
        app.FindGrepPreferences.FindWhat = "(?<=\t)(\d{4}.*~b)"
        doc.ChangeGrep()
```